# Quick way to add Webcam filter on the Mac to make hair appear darker?

Tags: macos, mac, camera, webcam

Is there a quick method without using 3rd party apps, so that when Zoom or Google Meeting is used, I can make the camera take my image so that the hair appears darker color (or make it a certain color?).

The reason is, for example, if I have a little grey hair and instead of dyeing my hair, if there is a system level camera filter I can use, so that the hair appears more blonde or more brown, then I can go on video conferencing without doing any hair dye.

Third party solution is ok, but it would be best if it can be standard macOS built in methods. If it is a solution for Zoom or Google Meeting, it may work, but if the group meeting or interview is done using one app or another, then it won't work any more, so system level filter would be best. Thanks very much.

There seems to be one solution here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cStG_x-6jKw but it needs to use Automator / AppleScript, which I don't quite understand why not just in some kind of settings.

Comment: There's no "quick", built-in method: you would have to use a third-party filter. The Quartz Composition Filters shown in the YouTube link don't offer hair color.